# Catching signals in RPython

Tags: signals, pypy, rpython

How does one catch signals (specifically/especially `SIGINT`) in a translated RPython program?

I've grepped through the PyPy source tree, I found the CPython `signal` module, and attempting to use this in the translated program gives the expected error during translation:

```
[translation:ERROR]  Exception: unexpected prebuilt constant: <built-in function signal>
```

There is also [`pypy.module.signal`](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/7fc6072593dd/pypy/module/signal) but I don't know if that's what I should be using, or how to use it. That module does provide a `signal` function, but it takes an additional `space` parameter; these `space` parameters appear a few places through the source tree and I can't work out what they refer to, or what I should pass there.

**Background:** I'm looking to have a computation that runs for an arbitrary length of time, but capture `^C` so that I can print out the results so far before the program exits. (The obvious `try: ... except KeyboardInterrupt: ...` around the main loop doesn't work either.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use the RPython signal handling functions, which are a little wrapper over the platform ones. The functions you'll need are in `pypy.module.signal.interp_signal`. For example, `pypysig_ignore(signum)` is equivalent to `signal(signum, SIG_IGN)`. Call `pypysig_poll` to return the pending signal if there is one. Here's a excerpt to ask for the signal to be handled and wait for it to arrive

```
pypysig_setflag(signum)
while True:
    n = pypysig_poll()
    if n < 0:
        # No signals pending
        break
    if n == signum:
        handle_signal()
```

Comment: Thanks, presumably you'd run this off the main thread? That looks a lot like a (very) busy wait. Also, [interp_signal.signal](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/7fc6072593dd/pypy/module/signal/interp_signal.py#cl-249) isn't useful/useable? It appears to be doing all the above in a managed way, but I can't work out what the `space` parameter is (I guess that's actually my real question; I understand if you're not familiar with the internals of RPython and so can't answer that... neither can I, haha!)

Comment: (I've added a bit more background to the question, if that is at all relevant.)

Comment: You have to occasionally run the loop I gave to check for interrupts.

Comment: `interp_signal.signal` is the interface for the Python interpreter.

Comment: Do you have some sort of reference for that? I can't find `interp_signal.signal` used anywhere in the source tree.

Comment: It's called when someone uses `signal.signal` in the Python code run by the interpreter.